# I found a locked golden chest but can't find the key. Where is it?

Tags: torchlight-2

I explored the large area called the Temple Steppes and found a locked golden chest. I'm guessing there is a large champion I need to kill in order to get the key but I can't seem to find it. I've looked all over the map and had no luck. Is this a bug? Is the key somewhere else? Did I really just miss the champion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Find an enemy called Bittersprite on the same map as the Locked Golden Chest. Bittersprite looks like a large wasp or hornet. It is not necessarily near the chest, it can be anywhere on the map. You can see it floating in the top-right area of this screenshot:

[image: Bittersprite]

Kill the Bittersprite and it will drop a Golden Key. The key will not appear in your inventory when you pick it up, but in the top-right corner of the screen it will say **-You Found-** and show a picture of the key. You can now open the Locked Golden Chest.

Answer (score 1):

You have to kill a mob called Bitter Spire, it's a bird

It's located to the right of the waypoint.

Take 2 right turns from the waypoint, basically head west.  It's no more than a 4 second run from the way point.  You may have to clear the map first, like I did.

Comment: Just a note: the maps and mobs are randomly generated. His Temple Steppes may be different from your Temple Steppes, and the Bitter Spire may be in a different location.

Comment: I looked around my waypoint and found no mobs to kill. My Waypoint (and zone entrance) was in the west and the chest was in the very far east. Random maps for sure, I guess I just didn't get the mob to spawn.

Comment: I came across a Locked Golden Chest in the area just before the Temple Steppes and cleared the whole map without coming across the mob that drops the key. I came back through later and the mob spawned. I have also noticed that if you kill the mob and pick up the key in one area, you can't take it with you to another area.